# Multiply a constant number in a .dat file from the command line

Tags: linux, sed

I have a .dat file which has data in rows. Each row is closed by a curly bracket and numbers are separated by a comma. I want to multiply the entire file contents with a constant number from the command line, so that I don't have to do it manually.

eg.

```
:{0, 16, 0, 0, 0, 0.0187782, 0.053621, 0.0045498, 3.2744e-05, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}:
```

How should I do it?

Comment: what did you try and what is the expected output?

Comment: i used -  echo "$((0.5*myfilename.dat))" . The expected output - I want each number in my file to be multiplied by say 0.5

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can do things like this with `Perl`, e.g.:

```
echo 10,20,999| perl -ple 's/(\d+)/$1*10/ge'
100,200,9990
```

That will fail with negative numbers and exponentials, so you need a better regex to specify how your numbers might look. I am no expert on regexes but something like this seems close to me at least:

```
echo ":{0, 16, 0.0187782, 0.053621, 0.0045498, 3.2744e-05}:" | perl -ple 's/([-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+([eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?)/$1*10/ge'

:{0, 160, 0.187782, 0.53621, 0.045498, 0.00032744}:
```

If anyone has a better regex, please say an I'll update.

If your data are in a file, you can do:

```
perl ... < file.dat
```

Comment: To the down-voter: If you are going to down-vote, as is surely your right, please at least leave a comment saying what is so terribly wrong and objectionable about my answer so we can all benefit from your knowledge. We are all here to learn. Thank you.

Comment: Hello, This command worked perfectly- perl -ple 's/([-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+([eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?)/$1*10/ge' > myfilename.dat. Thanks a lot....

Comment: Excellent - glad it helped!